# Setting up gemfile for Jekyll - unclear what is wrong

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, gemfile

I'm trying to setup a gh-pages site with Jekyll.

When running `jekyll server` I run into the following error message:

````
        10: from /Users/a56z/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/bin/jekyll:23:in `<main>'
         9: from /Users/a56z/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/bin/jekyll:23:in `load'
         8: from /Users/a56z/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/jekyll-4.0.0/exe/jekyll:11:in `<top (required)>'
         7: from /Users/a56z/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/jekyll-4.0.0/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:52:in `require_from_bundler'
         6: from /Users/a56z/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler.rb:107:in `setup'
         5: from /Users/a56z/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:26:in `setup'
         4: from /Users/a56z/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:26:in `map'
         3: from /Users/a56z/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:148:in `each'
         2: from /Users/a56z/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:148:in `each'
         1: from /Users/a56z/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:31:in `block in setup'
/Users/a56z/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:319:in `check_for_activated_spec!': You have already activated i18n 1.6.0, but your Gemfile requires i18n 0.9.5. Prepending `bundle exec` to your command may solve this. (Gem::LoadError) ```
````

My Gemfile looks as follows:

````
# Hello! This is where you manage which Jekyll version is used to run.
# When you want to use a different version, change it below, save the
# file and run `bundle install`. Run Jekyll with `bundle exec`, like so:
#
#     bundle exec jekyll serve
gem 'github-pages'
#
# This will help ensure the proper Jekyll version is running.
# Happy Jekylling!
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'jekyll', '3.8.6'

group :jekyll_plugins do
  gem 'jekyll-feed'
  gem 'jekyll-seo-tag'
end```
````

Please advise what I'm missing, I've been searching the web but couldn't find anything to make this work.

Also running `bundle exec jekyll server` doesn't work

---

I have also simplified the gemfile to this:

```
gem "jekyll"
gem "minima"

group :jekyll_plugins do
  gem "jekyll-feed"
end
```

but even like so I get this error:

```
Configuration file: /Users/a56z/code/a56z/blog/my_pytter_blog/_config.yml
            Source: /Users/a56z/code/a56z/blog/my_pytter_blog
       Destination: /Users/a56z/code/a56z/blog/my_pytter_blog/_site
 Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
      Generating...
       Jekyll Feed: Generating feed for posts
                    done in 0.229 seconds.
 Auto-regeneration: enabled for '/Users/a56z/code/a56z/blog/my_pytter_blog'
bundler: failed to load command: jekyll (/Users/a56z/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/bin/jekyll)
Errno::EADDRINUSE: Address already in use - bind(2) for 127.0.0.1:4000
  /Users/a56z/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/socket.rb:201:in `bind'
  /Users/a56z/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/socket.rb:201:in `listen'
  /Users/a56z/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/socket.rb:764:in `block in tcp_server_sockets'
  /Users/a56z/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/socket.rb:227:in `each'
  /Users/a56z/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/socket.rb:227:in `foreach'
  /Users/a56z/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/socket.rb:762:in `tcp_server_sockets'
  /Users/a56z/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/webrick/utils.rb:65:in `create_listeners'
  /Users/a56z/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/webrick/server.rb:127:in `listen'
  /Users/a56z/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/webrick/server.rb:108:in `initialize'
  /Users/a56z/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:47:in `initialize'
  /Users/a56z/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/jekyll-4.0.0/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:215:in `new'
  /Users/a56z/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/jekyll-4.0.0/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:215:in `start_up_webrick'
  /Users/a56z/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/jekyll-4.0.0/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:102:in `process'
  /Users/a56z/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/jekyll-4.0.0/lib/jekyll/command.rb:89:in `block in process_with_graceful_fail'
  /Users/a56z/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/jekyll-4.0.0/lib/jekyll/command.rb:89:in `each'
  /Users/a56z/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/jekyll-4.0.0/lib/jekyll/command.rb:89:in `process_with_graceful_fail'
  /Users/a56z/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/jekyll-4.0.0/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:86:in `block (2 levels) in init_with_program'
  /Users/a56z/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `block in execute'
  /Users/a56z/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `each'
  /Users/a56z/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `execute'
  /Users/a56z/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/program.rb:42:in `go'
  /Users/a56z/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary.rb:19:in `program'
  /Users/a56z/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/jekyll-4.0.0/exe/jekyll:15:in `<top (required)>'
  /Users/a56z/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/bin/jekyll:23:in `load'
  /Users/a56z/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/bin/jekyll:23:in `<top (required)>'
```

Comment: did you run `bundle install` prior to `bundle exec jekyll serve`? (also note serve, not serveR)

Comment: Yes, I just tried it again just in case but it doesn't work still.
I simplified the gemfile to `source "https://rubygems.org"

gem "jekyll"
gem "minima"

group :jekyll_plugins do
  gem "jekyll-feed"
end` but still it doesn't run on localhost

Comment: I just updated the initial post with the edited gemfile results.

Comment: Try to delete **Gemfile.lock** and run `bundle install`.

Comment: thx, I actually deleted the whole thing and used some templates I found on the web instead. There are some dependency issues with the gh-pages gem, deleting the Gemfile.lock would probably make it work, good point!